# Google API: refresh tokens suddenly stopped working ("invalid_grant")

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

All accesses (a dozen) stopped working returning the error "invalid_grant".

I have revoked the application access for one of the user, got a new one, and this access is now working again with a new refresh token.

I wonder what might have happened? I doubt all users changed their password (I read that this can revoked access) and refresh tokens don't have an expire limite.

Everything was working fine until now.

Answer (score 2):

Refresh tokens should not expire if a user changes there password.  That is kind of the point with a refresh token.

Refresh tokens can expire if

1. the refresh token hasn't been used for six months to get a new access token.
2. if the user in question revokes access via their Google Account.
3. To many refresh tokens.  When a user authenticate your application you get a refresh token associated with your project and said user.  If the user authenticates your application again you get another refresh token both will work. You can keep doing this until you reach the magic number of 25 at which time the first refresh token will automatically expire.

Number three could be your problem if you are not ensuring that you are always saving the most resent refresh token. Or if your users have multiple versions of your application running.

If you are having an issues with all of your users I think the problem could be that, Invalid grant can also be the result of Your server’s clock is not in sync with [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).

Comment: About NTP, I have just revoked/created a new access with a user and it works. So it's only with all old refresh tokens, not all users.

Comment: How old are they its not an issue with Nr 1?   In my experience the problem is normally related to number 3.

Comment: At least one was used last week. About number 3, I'm not sure I understand it right. How can a user authenticate an application multiple times. If I try that it skips the authentication form and does not return a new refresh token.

Comment: Every time you pop up the Authentication form (please give x application access to y) you are requesting authentication from the user.   Do that 26 times and the first refresh token you got should expire. (you can test it by spamming authentication yourself)  I think it depends upon which language you are using if a refresh token is returned and the client library if you are using that.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration seams they may have uped it to 50 now.

Comment: Ok, with approval_prompt indeed you can ask for a refresh_token multiple times. I was allowing only one authentication. I still don't understand where the problem comes from, but as for now I will just ask users to reauthenticate to get a new refresh token..